# Import-Clixml will read PSObject values as #text and not include the real data

Tags: powershell

I am working on a tool and this tool will gather data from the customer environment and will then data these gathered data into PSCustomObjects then will dump the Object into an XML file using the Export-Clixml.

The Problem is in some Objects the Export-Clixml will dump the data and when using the Import-Clixml these object will have the value of #text instead the real value.

For example:

I am getting the Certificate info from the NSX Manager using PowerNsx and then add it to a PSCustomObject

```
$NsxManagerCertificate = Get-NsxManagerCertificate
$TestObject = [PSCustomObject] {
     NsxManagerCertificate = $NsxManagerCertificate
}
Export-Clixml -InputObject $TestObject -Path E:\TestDump.xml
```

If I checked the variables output you will get the real data:

```
C:\Users\Administrator> $NsxManagerCertificate


subjectCn            : CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss
issuerCn             : CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss
version              : 3
serialNumber         : 49044a14
signatureAlgo        : SHA256WITHRSA
signature            : 0b 5d c7 cb ab 58 0d 9a ff 03 e9 0a e5 91 61 64 16 22 c7 c2 21 28 50 f2 ad 02 21 e9 48 4e f6 72 d3 91 f1 19 3e 3e 25 3a fd 28 ab 81 e2 6c d1 35 51 dc 13 c4 22 f3 cb 53 db 6d c5 0c fe ff 6b 0b cd fc 17 d2 d5 bd d0 b8 13 e2 
                       53 e7 2b 1e 8a 84 ee 54 f4 dc b3 7d 1a 70 4b 71 12 42 6b 2c b5 1c 65 85 94 9d f5 00 7c 28 0f 6f 5b 15 b4 fe 67 e2 fa 4c 10 6c 31 a4 4a df 48 f2 c1 a1 66 e5 d2 0a 80 3e f4 02 c3 75 95 4c e0 d8 5b 90 74 9a 85 56 b4 f2 9e 2b 
                       c3 c7 f4 71 fa 43 b2 c2 1e 65 a6 0b 8b eb fc 39 77 bd 04 39 b4 99 64 81 d5 0d 81 88 a9 33 63 72 9f a4 b3 d7 c5 33 97 14 d5 be 3f 8e a9 de fd 0f 1c 3d 63 fd 0c ff e2 12 03 59 53 f1 a5 96 cb a6 03 23 4b ef 71 38 0e 96 fb 85 
                       4d 4c a8 8b 48 50 a6 e0 ff c6 f9 25 b5 8f d4 d2 0c 82 4c ff 9f e3 ef 9a e9 44 57 c5 3c 06 b8 b5 f9 2e
notBefore            : 1527008785000
notAfter             : 1842368785000
issuer               : CN=CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss,OU=NSX,O=VMware Inc.,L=Palo Alto,ST=CA,C=US
subject              : CN=CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss,OU=NSX,O=VMware Inc.,L=Palo Alto,ST=CA,C=US
publicKeyAlgo        : RSA
publicKeyLength      : 2048
rsaPublicKeyModulus  : 00 a5 7d 07 71 38 f5 39 fd 64 61 15 4a a6 ec 2a 51 d6 1b 49 08 6b 37 74 ae 8e 5e 21 db a5 48 73 e1 45 5b 02 5c 60 0c 9c 49 77 45 a4 43 f9 2b 05 a8 02 3b cb e7 17 89 18 79 38 5b a0 1d 77 3b c3 90 3d 39 8c 5e 25 90 80 d0 a0 
                       df f1 32 52 4c 46 8b 86 1f 67 5b 1a ee 56 3e d0 bf cc 45 5d 7a b8 f7 65 d0 4b 92 94 9f 1f 22 0d ae a6 d2 cb e6 00 92 f6 41 1b 52 4b 1d ba dc 24 04 e3 f5 2c c5 26 f0 d0 2c 02 b4 6b c2 f0 12 e7 20 c5 fe 4f d2 8f 12 8d 2d 2c 
                       3e 8a cb 63 f7 d9 37 0c fd 43 53 e3 14 cd 51 b5 68 0d e7 59 ad a3 8e 28 53 72 d1 97 65 f2 bf fb 6c 78 63 d8 57 fe 8f 6b 89 53 ac a2 0c 0d 83 bd be d5 14 7b 4c cf 15 22 60 17 1e 1f f7 28 7f 64 ac 28 a7 26 d3 bc c7 5a c0 42 
                       e6 34 00 57 62 99 6a 0c 4c 54 a4 6e b7 b8 73 43 1d 65 f7 b8 cd fc 99 75 8c 49 f1 0f 72 70 1b 4c 47 0e 7b
rsaPublicKeyExponent : 10001
sha1Hash             : 05:69:31:14:c9:41:0d:30:d6:52:e6:83:e8:6a:56:ad:1e:84:a5:37
md5Hash              : 1c:cb:26:9b:2b:b5:09:6f:b1:cd:91:00:c3:f7:34:9f
isCa                 : false
isValid              : true


C:\Users\Administrator> $TestObject.NsxManagerCertificate


subjectCn            : CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss
issuerCn             : CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss
version              : 3
serialNumber         : 49044a14
signatureAlgo        : SHA256WITHRSA
signature            : 0b 5d c7 cb ab 58 0d 9a ff 03 e9 0a e5 91 61 64 16 22 c7 c2 21 28 50 f2 ad 02 21 e9 48 4e f6 72 d3 91 f1 19 3e 3e 25 3a fd 28 ab 81 e2 6c d1 35 51 dc 13 c4 22 f3 cb 53 db 6d c5 0c fe ff 6b 0b cd fc 17 d2 d5 bd d0 b8 13 e2 
                       53 e7 2b 1e 8a 84 ee 54 f4 dc b3 7d 1a 70 4b 71 12 42 6b 2c b5 1c 65 85 94 9d f5 00 7c 28 0f 6f 5b 15 b4 fe 67 e2 fa 4c 10 6c 31 a4 4a df 48 f2 c1 a1 66 e5 d2 0a 80 3e f4 02 c3 75 95 4c e0 d8 5b 90 74 9a 85 56 b4 f2 9e 2b 
                       c3 c7 f4 71 fa 43 b2 c2 1e 65 a6 0b 8b eb fc 39 77 bd 04 39 b4 99 64 81 d5 0d 81 88 a9 33 63 72 9f a4 b3 d7 c5 33 97 14 d5 be 3f 8e a9 de fd 0f 1c 3d 63 fd 0c ff e2 12 03 59 53 f1 a5 96 cb a6 03 23 4b ef 71 38 0e 96 fb 85 
                       4d 4c a8 8b 48 50 a6 e0 ff c6 f9 25 b5 8f d4 d2 0c 82 4c ff 9f e3 ef 9a e9 44 57 c5 3c 06 b8 b5 f9 2e
notBefore            : 1527008785000
notAfter             : 1842368785000
issuer               : CN=CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss,OU=NSX,O=VMware Inc.,L=Palo Alto,ST=CA,C=US
subject              : CN=CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss,OU=NSX,O=VMware Inc.,L=Palo Alto,ST=CA,C=US
publicKeyAlgo        : RSA
publicKeyLength      : 2048
rsaPublicKeyModulus  : 00 a5 7d 07 71 38 f5 39 fd 64 61 15 4a a6 ec 2a 51 d6 1b 49 08 6b 37 74 ae 8e 5e 21 db a5 48 73 e1 45 5b 02 5c 60 0c 9c 49 77 45 a4 43 f9 2b 05 a8 02 3b cb e7 17 89 18 79 38 5b a0 1d 77 3b c3 90 3d 39 8c 5e 25 90 80 d0 a0 
                       df f1 32 52 4c 46 8b 86 1f 67 5b 1a ee 56 3e d0 bf cc 45 5d 7a b8 f7 65 d0 4b 92 94 9f 1f 22 0d ae a6 d2 cb e6 00 92 f6 41 1b 52 4b 1d ba dc 24 04 e3 f5 2c c5 26 f0 d0 2c 02 b4 6b c2 f0 12 e7 20 c5 fe 4f d2 8f 12 8d 2d 2c 
                       3e 8a cb 63 f7 d9 37 0c fd 43 53 e3 14 cd 51 b5 68 0d e7 59 ad a3 8e 28 53 72 d1 97 65 f2 bf fb 6c 78 63 d8 57 fe 8f 6b 89 53 ac a2 0c 0d 83 bd be d5 14 7b 4c cf 15 22 60 17 1e 1f f7 28 7f 64 ac 28 a7 26 d3 bc c7 5a c0 42 
                       e6 34 00 57 62 99 6a 0c 4c 54 a4 6e b7 b8 73 43 1d 65 f7 b8 cd fc 99 75 8c 49 f1 0f 72 70 1b 4c 47 0e 7b
rsaPublicKeyExponent : 10001
sha1Hash             : 05:69:31:14:c9:41:0d:30:d6:52:e6:83:e8:6a:56:ad:1e:84:a5:37
md5Hash              : 1c:cb:26:9b:2b:b5:09:6f:b1:cd:91:00:c3:f7:34:9f
isCa                 : false
isValid              : true
```

However if you check the xml file you will get #text instead of the read data

```
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <Obj RefId="0">
    <TN RefId="0">
      <T>System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject</T>
      <T>System.Object</T>
    </TN>
    <MS>
      <Obj N="NsxManagerCertificate" RefId="1">
        <TN RefId="1">
          <T>System.Xml.XmlElement</T>
          <T>System.Xml.XmlLinkedNode</T>
          <T>System.Xml.XmlNode</T>
          <T>System.Object</T>
        </TN>
        <IE>
          <Obj RefId="2">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="3">
                <TN RefId="2">
                  <T>System.Xml.XmlText</T>
                  <T>System.Xml.XmlCharacterData</T>
                  <T>System.Xml.XmlLinkedNode</T>
                  <T>System.Xml.XmlNode</T>
                  <T>System.Object</T>
                </TN>
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="4">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="5">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="6">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="7">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">3</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="8">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="9">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">49044a14</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="10">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="11">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">SHA256WITHRSA</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="12">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="13">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">0b 5d c7 cb ab 58 0d 9a ff 03 e9 0a e5 91 61 64 16 22 c7 c2 21 28 50 f2 ad 02 21 e9 48 4e f6 72 d3 91 f1 19 3e 3e 25 3a fd 28 ab 81 e2 6c d1 35 51 dc 13 c4 22 f3 cb 53 db 6d c5 0c fe ff 6b 0b cd fc 17 d2 d5 bd d0 b8 13 e2 53 e7 2b 1e 8a 84 ee 54 f4 dc b3 7d 1a 70 4b 71 12 42 6b 2c b5 1c 65 85 94 9d f5 00 7c 28 0f 6f 5b 15 b4 fe 67 e2 fa 4c 10 6c 31 a4 4a df 48 f2 c1 a1 66 e5 d2 0a 80 3e f4 02 c3 75 95 4c e0 d8 5b 90 74 9a 85 56 b4 f2 9e 2b c3 c7 f4 71 fa 43 b2 c2 1e 65 a6 0b 8b eb fc 39 77 bd 04 39 b4 99 64 81 d5 0d 81 88 a9 33 63 72 9f a4 b3 d7 c5 33 97 14 d5 be 3f 8e a9 de fd 0f 1c 3d 63 fd 0c ff e2 12 03 59 53 f1 a5 96 cb a6 03 23 4b ef 71 38 0e 96 fb 85 4d 4c a8 8b 48 50 a6 e0 ff c6 f9 25 b5 8f d4 d2 0c 82 4c ff 9f e3 ef 9a e9 44 57 c5 3c 06 b8 b5 f9 2e</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="14">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="15">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">1527008785000</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="16">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="17">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">1842368785000</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="18">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="19">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">CN=CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss,OU=NSX,O=VMware Inc.,L=Palo Alto,ST=CA,C=US</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="20">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="21">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">CN=CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss,OU=NSX,O=VMware Inc.,L=Palo Alto,ST=CA,C=US</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="22">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="23">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">RSA</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="24">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="25">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">2048</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="26">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="27">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">00 a5 7d 07 71 38 f5 39 fd 64 61 15 4a a6 ec 2a 51 d6 1b 49 08 6b 37 74 ae 8e 5e 21 db a5 48 73 e1 45 5b 02 5c 60 0c 9c 49 77 45 a4 43 f9 2b 05 a8 02 3b cb e7 17 89 18 79 38 5b a0 1d 77 3b c3 90 3d 39 8c 5e 25 90 80 d0 a0 df f1 32 52 4c 46 8b 86 1f 67 5b 1a ee 56 3e d0 bf cc 45 5d 7a b8 f7 65 d0 4b 92 94 9f 1f 22 0d ae a6 d2 cb e6 00 92 f6 41 1b 52 4b 1d ba dc 24 04 e3 f5 2c c5 26 f0 d0 2c 02 b4 6b c2 f0 12 e7 20 c5 fe 4f d2 8f 12 8d 2d 2c 3e 8a cb 63 f7 d9 37 0c fd 43 53 e3 14 cd 51 b5 68 0d e7 59 ad a3 8e 28 53 72 d1 97 65 f2 bf fb 6c 78 63 d8 57 fe 8f 6b 89 53 ac a2 0c 0d 83 bd be d5 14 7b 4c cf 15 22 60 17 1e 1f f7 28 7f 64 ac 28 a7 26 d3 bc c7 5a c0 42 e6 34 00 57 62 99 6a 0c 4c 54 a4 6e b7 b8 73 43 1d 65 f7 b8 cd fc 99 75 8c 49 f1 0f 72 70 1b 4c 47 0e 7b</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="28">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="29">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">10001</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="30">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="31">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">05:69:31:14:c9:41:0d:30:d6:52:e6:83:e8:6a:56:ad:1e:84:a5:37</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="32">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="33">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">1c:cb:26:9b:2b:b5:09:6f:b1:cd:91:00:c3:f7:34:9f</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="34">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="35">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">false</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="36">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="37">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">true</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
        </IE>
        <Props>
          <S N="subjectCn">CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss</S>
          <S N="issuerCn">CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss</S>
          <S N="version">3</S>
          <S N="serialNumber">49044a14</S>
          <S N="signatureAlgo">SHA256WITHRSA</S>
          <S N="signature">0b 5d c7 cb ab 58 0d 9a ff 03 e9 0a e5 91 61 64 16 22 c7 c2 21 28 50 f2 ad 02 21 e9 48 4e f6 72 d3 91 f1 19 3e 3e 25 3a fd 28 ab 81 e2 6c d1 35 51 dc 13 c4 22 f3 cb 53 db 6d c5 0c fe ff 6b 0b cd fc 17 d2 d5 bd d0 b8 13 e2 53 e7 2b 1e 8a 84 ee 54 f4 dc b3 7d 1a 70 4b 71 12 42 6b 2c b5 1c 65 85 94 9d f5 00 7c 28 0f 6f 5b 15 b4 fe 67 e2 fa 4c 10 6c 31 a4 4a df 48 f2 c1 a1 66 e5 d2 0a 80 3e f4 02 c3 75 95 4c e0 d8 5b 90 74 9a 85 56 b4 f2 9e 2b c3 c7 f4 71 fa 43 b2 c2 1e 65 a6 0b 8b eb fc 39 77 bd 04 39 b4 99 64 81 d5 0d 81 88 a9 33 63 72 9f a4 b3 d7 c5 33 97 14 d5 be 3f 8e a9 de fd 0f 1c 3d 63 fd 0c ff e2 12 03 59 53 f1 a5 96 cb a6 03 23 4b ef 71 38 0e 96 fb 85 4d 4c a8 8b 48 50 a6 e0 ff c6 f9 25 b5 8f d4 d2 0c 82 4c ff 9f e3 ef 9a e9 44 57 c5 3c 06 b8 b5 f9 2e</S>
          <S N="notBefore">1527008785000</S>
          <S N="notAfter">1842368785000</S>
          <S N="issuer">CN=CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss,OU=NSX,O=VMware Inc.,L=Palo Alto,ST=CA,C=US</S>
          <S N="subject">CN=CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss,OU=NSX,O=VMware Inc.,L=Palo Alto,ST=CA,C=US</S>
          <S N="publicKeyAlgo">RSA</S>
          <S N="publicKeyLength">2048</S>
          <S N="rsaPublicKeyModulus">00 a5 7d 07 71 38 f5 39 fd 64 61 15 4a a6 ec 2a 51 d6 1b 49 08 6b 37 74 ae 8e 5e 21 db a5 48 73 e1 45 5b 02 5c 60 0c 9c 49 77 45 a4 43 f9 2b 05 a8 02 3b cb e7 17 89 18 79 38 5b a0 1d 77 3b c3 90 3d 39 8c 5e 25 90 80 d0 a0 df f1 32 52 4c 46 8b 86 1f 67 5b 1a ee 56 3e d0 bf cc 45 5d 7a b8 f7 65 d0 4b 92 94 9f 1f 22 0d ae a6 d2 cb e6 00 92 f6 41 1b 52 4b 1d ba dc 24 04 e3 f5 2c c5 26 f0 d0 2c 02 b4 6b c2 f0 12 e7 20 c5 fe 4f d2 8f 12 8d 2d 2c 3e 8a cb 63 f7 d9 37 0c fd 43 53 e3 14 cd 51 b5 68 0d e7 59 ad a3 8e 28 53 72 d1 97 65 f2 bf fb 6c 78 63 d8 57 fe 8f 6b 89 53 ac a2 0c 0d 83 bd be d5 14 7b 4c cf 15 22 60 17 1e 1f f7 28 7f 64 ac 28 a7 26 d3 bc c7 5a c0 42 e6 34 00 57 62 99 6a 0c 4c 54 a4 6e b7 b8 73 43 1d 65 f7 b8 cd fc 99 75 8c 49 f1 0f 72 70 1b 4c 47 0e 7b</S>
          <S N="rsaPublicKeyExponent">10001</S>
          <S N="sha1Hash">05:69:31:14:c9:41:0d:30:d6:52:e6:83:e8:6a:56:ad:1e:84:a5:37</S>
          <S N="md5Hash">1c:cb:26:9b:2b:b5:09:6f:b1:cd:91:00:c3:f7:34:9f</S>
          <S N="isCa">false</S>
          <S N="isValid">true</S>
        </Props>
      </Obj>
    </MS>
  </Obj>
</Objs>
```

Then use the Import-Clixml to get the data and you will find the values are #text (I think this is reading only the #text values in each object)

```
C:\Users\Administrator> $TestImport = Import-Clixml -Path E:\TestDump.xml

 C:\Users\Administrator> $TestImport

NsxManagerCertificate          
---------------------          
{#text, #text, #text, #text...}



 C:\Users\Administrator> $TestImport.NsxManagerCertificate
#text
#text
#text
#text
#text
#text
#text
#text
#text
#text
#text
#text
#text
#text
#text
#text
#text
#text
```

Comment: Is it necessary to make a PSCustomObject? Have you tried to save $NsxManagerCertificate directly?

Comment: Hi Mootonero, Thank you for your advice. I won't be able to save it by itself as I am getting a lot more and if I saved each one by itself it will end up having 100s of files and it will be difficult to manage the import

Comment: Have you looked at this article? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34076478/is-there-a-way-to-pass-serializable-objects-to-a-powershell-script-with-start-pr.

Comment: Hi montonero, thanks for the help, i have checked the link and tried the 2 options [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize and [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize but it did not work. i think this is an issue with how the object is created in the first place. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

[`Export-Clixml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-clixml?view=powershell-6) has a `-Depth` parameter, which , unfortunately defaults to 2.

Since your top object is level 1, and your `NsxmanagerCertificate` is level 2, it seems that you may need to increase that value!

```
Export-Clixml -InputObject $TestObject -Path E:\TestDump.xml -Depth 10
```

You can play around with the number (3 might be fine for you) or just throw caution to the wind and go big with it.

Comment: Hi briantist, Thanks for your help. I know about the depth parameter and I have tried it as well but did not help much. I have found the main issue I think. so the $NsxManagerCertificate is of type XmlElement and if I re-create it as a PSCustomObject it works like charm. do you know of any way to convert a XmlElement to a PSCustomObject