# Cannot convert the "System.Security.SecureString" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Security.SecureString"

Tags: powershell, server

I have a problem with an app that I am creating: this app can configure from a remote device a server/PC through IP, Username, Password. There is a script I made in PowerShell that can add User with password in server (New-LocalUser), but when I'll execute it, it gives me this error

```
Cannot bind parameter 'Password'. Cannot convert the "System.Security.SecureString" value of type "System.String" to
type "System.Security.SecureString".
```

The password is saved in a temporary file and convert into secure string in PS script, so I don't understand why it doesn't work

Here the script

```
$path = (Get-Location).ToString() + "\..\..\script\PS\lib.ps1"
Import-Module -Name $path

$json = (Get-Location).ToString() + "\..\..\misc\json\user.json"
$userinfo = Get-Content $json | ConvertFrom-Json

$uj = (Get-Location).ToString() + "\..\..\misc\json\userToAdd.json"
$commands = Get-Content $uj | ConvertFrom-Json

$passtype = $commands.passwordType
$pass = $commands.password

if($commands.isEnable -eq "False"){
    $arg = '-Disabled '
}

if($commands.password -eq "")
{
    $arg = $arg + $commands.passwordType + '-NoPassword '
}else{
    $npass = $pass | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    $arg = $arg + $commands.passwordType + '-Password '
}

if($commands.Description -eq ""){
    $desc = " "
}else{
    $desc = " -Description " + $commands.Description + " "
}

$cmd = "New-LocalUser -Name " + $commands.Name + $desc + $arg + $npass
$cmd
$ScriptBlock =  [scriptblock]::Create($cmd)
ExcuteRemoteCommand -serverAddress $userinfo.ip -ServerUsername $userinfo.user -ServerPassword $userinfo.password -code $ScriptBlock

if($commands.logon -eq "True"){
    $cmd = "net user " + ($commands.Name).ToString() + " /logonpasswordchg:yes"
    $cmd
    $ScriptBlock =  [scriptblock]::Create($cmd)
    ExcuteRemoteCommand -serverAddress $userinfo.ip -ServerUsername $userinfo.user -ServerPassword $userinfo.password -code $ScriptBlock
}else{
    $cmd = "net user " + ($commands.Name).ToString() + " /logonpasswordchg:no"
    $cmd
    $ScriptBlock =  [scriptblock]::Create($cmd)
    ExcuteRemoteCommand -serverAddress $userinfo.ip -ServerUsername $userinfo.user -ServerPassword $userinfo.password -code $ScriptBlock
}
Read-Host
Exit
```

Comment: $SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString 'MyPassword' –asplaintext –force

Comment: It's always a good idea to include relevant piece of code that causes the error.

Comment: I have just done this, it doesn't work

Comment: What does your function `ExcuteRemoteCommand` expect for parameter `ServerPassword` ? Judging by the error message in there it is defined as `[string]` and if so, you should send it a plain-text password and if needed convert to `[securestring]` inside that function.

Comment: You can't pass a securedstring as *AsPlainText* to [`New-LocalUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/new-localuser?view=powershell-5.1) you will need to serialize/deserialize it, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/34076478/1701026

Comment: @iRon I'll try and I'll tell you if it works

Comment: $Secure_String_Pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString "P@ssW0rD!" -AsPlainText -Force

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find a solution for my problem. I used the command `NET`, so here the che command line that I used

```
NET USER $user $pass /ADD
```

For the other parameters, I'll pass after it creates the user

> $pass is **NOT** a secure string!