# Escape double quotes in powershell -Command

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

Due to some limitations, I have to execute the Power Shell command from Windows Command Prompt

```
powershell -Command "(gc C:\my_configuration.conf) -replace 'INSERT_URL', \`"https://mytestserver/WW48.2'22/testing.bin\`" | Out-File C:\my_configuration.conf"
```

However, I am constantly getting the `ParserError` like below

```
The string is missing the terminator: '.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

How should I properly wrap the URL string with double quotes? Thanks for answering.

Comment: [Quoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules) and [parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing) PowerShell command will probably always be a hassle. Anyways, try to workaround embedded double quotes: `powershell -Command "(gc C:\my_configuration.conf) -replace 'INSERT_URL', 'https://mytestserver/WW48.2''22/testing.bin' | Out-File C:\my_configuration.conf"` or simply [encoded the command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73541687/1701026).

Comment: @iRon I agree with you, unfortunately I have no control over URL as it's being parsed as an argument, and it always contains `'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `` ` `` before `"`, and your command should work; that is, **when calling `powershell.exe` from `cmd.exe` / outside PowerShell,  use `\"` , not `` \`" `` (or `` `" ``)** in order to escape `"` chars.:

```bash
powershell -Command "(gc C:\my_configuration.conf) -replace 'INSERT_URL', \"https://mytestserver/WW48.2'22/testing.bin\" | Out-File C:\my_configuration.conf"
```

While you do need to escape the `"` characters embedded in your overall `"..."` command string, escaping them **as `\"`** is sufficient - no need to *also* use `` ` ``, the backtick, PowerShell's usual [escape character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters).

The PowerShell *CLI* ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)) expects `\`-escaping of `"`, so as to better align with most CLIs, even though *inside a PowerShell session* you need to use `` `" `` or (inside `"..."` only) `""`.<sup>[1]</sup>

You'd only need *both* `\` and `` ` `` - in the form `` `\" ``, note that `` ` `` comes *first* - if your embedded `"..."` *itself* contained `"` chars; a contrived example:

```bash
:: OK: Prints '3" of snow.'
powershell.exe -c " Write-Output \"3`\" of snow.\" "
```

---

As [iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701026/iron) notes, an **alternative solution** is to use embedded `'...'` quoting (single-quoting) instead.

Since your URL itself contains a `'` char., that character must then be escaped as `''`:

```bash
:: Note the use of '...' around https://... and the inner ' escaped as ''
powershell -Command "(gc C:\my_configuration.conf) -replace 'INSERT_URL', 'https://mytestserver/WW48.2''22/testing.bin' | Out-File C:\my_configuration.conf"
```

---

<sup>[1] In [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), whose CLI is [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), you may alternatively use `""` inside overall `"..." on the command line too, which is actually the more robust choice when calling from` cmd.exe`. When calling` powershell.exe`from`cmd.exe`, the robust choice is` "^""`(sic) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060341/45375). However, the PowerShell CLI recognizes`"`in _both_ editions, and`"`also works for`"`chars. _not_ inside overall`"..."`.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Try using this syntax, always works

```
"%windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Command "& { <# PUT ANYTHING HERE #> }"
```

You won't need to worry about escaping anything.

Your code:

```
"%windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Command "& { (gc C:\my_configuration.conf) -replace 'INSERT_URL', "https://mytestserver/WW48.2%2722/testing.bin" | Out-File 'C:\my_configuration.conf' }"
```

EDIT1: Check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) for URL special characters. the single quote (') can be handled by its replacement (%27) in your hard-coded string. (I changed it above in the 2nd code sample)

Comment: There's no reason to use `"& { ... }"` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter - just use `"..."` directly. Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected.

Comment: Apart from that, you still need to escape `"` chars. (which is the problem at hand), and, potentially, `%` chars. meant to be used verbatim when calling from a batch file (`cmd.exe`). Specifically, `%27` would need to be `%%27` when called from a batch file; at the interactive prompt, however, you must _not_ use `%%`. Anyway, such URL encoding is often not necessary, as it is performed on demand by various APIs.