# Forcing a powershell script to the next line

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that at one point will call 2 other powershell scripts to run. It runs one script to completion, then the other, but this causes it to take longer.  Can I force the script to execute the other scripts and continue cycling through?  When I used to run these scripts manually I would have 20-30 sessions running and walk away while it worked.  What I wrote took the monotony of clicking through them manually

Here's the parent script:

```
$List = Get-Content C:\archive\${env:id}.txt 
$Batch = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

foreach ($Data in $List){
    if ($Data -eq "" -or $data -eq $List[-1]){
        $ProjectName = $Batch[0]
        out-file C:\archive\"$ProjectName".txt

        foreach($Data in $Batch -ne $Batch[0]){
            Add-Content -Path C:\archive\"$ProjectName".txt -Exclude 
            $Batch[0] -Value $Data
        }
   -->  C:\archive\GetPrograms.ps1 $ProjectName 
   -->  C:\archive\GetNetwork.ps1 $ProjectName
        $Batch = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    }
    else{
        [void]$Batch.Add($Data)      
    }
}
```

**The parent script is not contingent on the data produced by the other 2 scripts.  It simply executes them by passing in data**

Comment: I commend to your attention the output of [`Get-Help Start-Process -Full`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6).

Comment: Thank you for that, I was able to ask a more exact question and found my solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776426/powershell-start-process-to-start-powershell-session-and-pass-local-variables

I used Start-Process Powershell -ArgumentList "C:/archive/script $ProjectName"

Comment: You should delete this question then

Comment: What I meant was I was able to google more specifically what I was looking for and that thread popped up

Comment: So did you find a solution or not?

Comment: I did, I used 'Start-Process -ArgumentList "C:/archive/script $ProjectName"'

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, based on your use case description, you really want to be looking at Parallel job/task/script processing.

Here is a post along the lines of what should satisfy your goals.

> How do I run my PowerShell scripts in parallel without using Jobs?
>
> Update - While this answer explains the process and mechanics of
>   PowerShell runspaces and how they can help you multi-thread
>   non-sequential workloads, fellow PowerShell aficionado Warren 'Cookie
>   Monster' F has gone the extra mile and incorporated these same
>   concepts into a single tool called Invoke-Parallel - it does what I
>   describe below, and he has since expanded it with optional switches
>   for logging and prepared session state including imported modules,
>   really cool stuff - I strongly recommend you check it out before
>   building you own shiny solution!
>
> https://serverfault.com/questions/626711/how-do-i-run-my-powershell-scripts-in-parallel-without-using-jobs